# Permission error when attempting to "write" pdf file (PDFLIB)?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, pdflib

I am working with  PDFlib's php code in an aws server and I keep getting he following error message

> Couldn't open PDF file 'file.pdf' for writing (permission denied)

I considered editing the permissions of this particular directory but the permissions are

> drwxrwxrwx+

Which seem to be appropriate for this script to function. Anyone has any idea why I am getting this permissions error?

Comment: Are you running the chmod recursively? What is the permission status of the file in question. Also, chmod 777 is not a great idea. Check the owner group of the directories and the files. Also, check which user is being used by php while executing the code with the help of this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input I have discovered the error.

My issue was that I was not specifying the path to my output document and temp directory.

I was declaring my output document as :

$output_document = "file.pdf"

instead of

$output_document = "/path/to/output/file.pdf"